# Optimal way to make tags in tax_query optional?

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, tax-query

Is there a more elegant way of doing this same thing.  I have three filters that I want to use to effect the results in the fourth field.  The pool, month, and tags are the filters.  I want the tags to ignored unless a tag is selected.  I kept running into the problem that if no tags were selected then results would show in the final field.

I came up with a cheap way of doing this, but I'm thinking there is a better way.

My approach is if the array for the tags is empty, then I'm changing the values of the $args variable that gets passed to the WP_Query.  During that check i am setting the value of a variable called $tag_status to not_empty if a tag happens to be selected.  Then I am just checking the value of that variable.

Take a look:

```
if($tag_status == "not_empty"){
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'daily-marriage-tips',
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'cat_tips',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $get_fym_dmt_pool,
                ),
                array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'cat_months',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => array_for_query($current_post_id, $get_fym_dmt_month_arr),
                ),
                array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'tag_tips',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => array_for_query($current_post_id, $get_fym_dmt_tags_arr),
                        'relation' => 'AND'
                ),
            ),
        );
    } else {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'daily-marriage-tips',
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'cat_tips',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $get_fym_dmt_pool,
                ),
                array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'cat_months',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => array_for_query($current_post_id, $get_fym_dmt_month_arr),
                )
            ),
        );
    }
```

I had tried putting the tags query into an array and setting the relation to "OR", but that made the 4th field empty unless I selected a tag.  I don't want to have to select a tag as that filter is a bonus filter. It's an optional thing. What would be the optimal approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good days. I found a better approach.

I have a custom function that looks at the multi-dimensional array and determines if they are empty.

Using that I found a way to dynamically add tax_query array into the main query for my wp_query.

I kept the "pool" in the main $args. I removed the month and tag.  If the user selects a month and then a tag these new array items will be added to the tax_query.

It ended up looking like this:

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'daily-marriage-tips',
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'cat_tips',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $get_fym_dmt_pool,
                ),
            )
        );

        // MONTHS ARRAY: check if the months array is empty
        is_array_empty($current_post_id, $get_fym_dmt_month_arr);
        if(is_array_empty($current_post_id, $get_fym_dmt_month_arr) == "not_empty"){
            array_push( 
                $args['tax_query'],
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'cat_months',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array_for_query($current_post_id, $get_fym_dmt_month_arr),
                    )
             );
        }


        // TAGS ARRAY: check if the tags array is empty
        is_array_empty($current_post_id, $get_fym_dmt_tags_arr);
        if(is_array_empty($current_post_id, $get_fym_dmt_tags_arr) == "not_empty"){
            array_push( 
                $args['tax_query'],
                array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'tag_tips',
                                'field'    => 'slug',
                                'terms'    => array_for_query($current_post_id, $get_fym_dmt_tags_arr),
                         )
             );
        }
```

My custom function is_array_empty accepts two arguments. The post id and the array you want to check.  Here is what it looks like:

```
// Check if the array is empty
function is_array_empty($pID, $array) {
    $item_arr = array();
    foreach($array as $item_arr) {
        if($item_arr[0] == NULL){
            $status = "empty";
        }else{
            $status = "not_empty";
        }           
    }
    return $status;
}
```